# Linq to entities search multiple tables with one query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I've been scratching my head for some hours trying to figure this one out. I need to search in several tables, using Entity Framework 6 and I've tried to make it work using joins with no luck at all. After a while, I decided to simply make it into several queries, which I'm not sure if ideal at all.

The following code works, but it's not pretty, I think (`searchTerm` is my search query which is a string):

```
// Search shareholders
var shareholders =
(from sh in ctx.FirmTypeShareholders.Where(x =>
x.CustomerID.ToString().Equals(searchTerm) ||
x.Firm_FirmType.Firm.ID.ToString().Equals(searchTerm))
    join firm in ctx.Firms on sh.Firm_FirmType.FirmID equals firm.ID
    select sh).ToList();

// Power plants by shareholder id
var powerPlantsByShareholder = (from sh in ctx.FirmTypeShareholders
                                join firm in ctx.Firms on sh.Firm_FirmType.FirmID equals firm.ID
                                from o in firm.Ownerships
                                join ppu in ctx.PowerPlantUnits on o.PowerPlantUnitID equals ppu.ID
                                join powerPlant in ctx.PowerPlants on ppu.PowerPlantID equals powerPlant.ID
                                where sh.CustomerID == 34
                                select new
                                {
                                    Shareholder = sh,
                                    PowerPlant = powerPlant
                                });

// Search persons
var persons = (from p in ctx.People.Where(x =>
x.ID.ToString().Equals(searchTerm) || x.Mobile.ToString().Equals(searchTerm) ||
x.Email.Equals(searchTerm) || x.Name.Contains(searchTerm))
                select p).ToList();

// Search power plants
var powerPlants = (from pp in ctx.PowerPlants.Where(x =>
x.ID.ToString().Equals(searchTerm) || x.GSRN.ToString().Equals(searchTerm) ||
x.EDIEL.ToString().Equals(searchTerm))
                    select pp).ToList();
```

Is there a way to make this work with a single query?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I think it's weird to let people search in primary key values (which I assume these `ID`s are). These should be meaningless in business terms. But for the rest, if it's useful to make people search "everywhere" then I don't think you can make this prettier.

Comment: The IDs are indeed primary keys :-) It's a business rule that I have to follow. It's good to know that I haven't missed any smart LINQ-trick to make it prettier, though. Thanks!